# How to generate Let's encrypt certificate with key type RSA/ECDSA using certbot?

Tags: ssl-certificate, rsa, lets-encrypt, certbot, ecdsa

Let's Encrypt Certbot default key type is changed to ECDSA with the latest version 2.0.0. How to specify the key type to generate RSA or ECDSA?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add key type parameter `--key-type` with desired value `rsa/ecdsa`. The below command is to generate `rsa` certificate with docker:

```
docker run -it -v /Users/thirumal/certificate:/etc/letsencrypt certbot/certbot certonly 
--manual --preferred-challenges dns --key-type rsa --email racetortoise@gmail.com 
--server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory --agree-tos -d '*.example.com'
```

I have a more complete guide to [generating free TLS/SSL certificates using Let's Encrypt](https://m-thirumal.github.io/installation_guide/#/TLS/let%27s_encrypt) published on my GitHub page.

Comment: I can't update the link as SO has too many pending edits, but here is the correct link: https://m-thirumal.github.io/installation_guide/#/TLS/let's_encrypt